# What is the proper date format for a given date

Tags: java, date

What is the proper date format for this date instance ..

```
10/10/2011 2:36:00 PM
```

I've used this ..

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
```

### edit

more code

```
Object temp = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("STARTDATE"); // date object from webserive
Date appointment.mStartDate = formatter.parse(temp.toString());
```

but it returned this date in this format ..

> Thu Nov 10 00:36:00 GMT+02:00 2011

Comment: What code did you use to actually format the date?

Comment: @Dave .. this : SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");

Comment: for this : 10/10/2011 2:36:00 PM I get it from a web service

Comment: That just creates a formatter, it doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: So you have a date *parsed* from a specific format-that's just a date, if you print it out it'll use the default date toString. If you want it formatted, you need to format it.

Comment: If you know, you can put in as answer ( how to format it )

Comment: Use the .format method of SimpleDateFormatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **parseObject**

```
Date appointment.mStartDate = (Date) formatter.parseObject(temp.toString());
```

Comment: Why? Getting the date isn't the issue, but even if it was, you're calling toString anyway. (And what do you think parseObject does?)

Answer (score 1):

> but it returned this date in this format ..
>
> ```
> Thu Nov 10 00:36:00 GMT+02:00 2011
> ```

You were thus doing `System.out.println(appointment.mStartDate);`? That's then perfectly fine. It's indeed the default format of [the `Date#toString()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29). When you pass a non-`String` object to `System.out.println()`, then its `toString()` method [will be called](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) and the returned `String` will be displayed.

If you want to display it in the same format as you have retrieved it, then you should be using the `SimpleDateFormat#format()` method to convert `Date` to a `String` in the desired format:

```
String dateString = formatter.format(appointment.mStartDate);
System.out.println(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is four acknowledged variants:
US M/D/YY
ISO-8601 YYYY-MM-DD
JIS ?
EUR DD.MM.YYYY

Comment: I always use YYYYMMDD internally
and depending on the situation, I use above

Answer (score 0):

What's your problem?  The date appears to have been parsed correctly for a timezone of +2 hours.  Naturally, when you simply print the `toString` description, the displayed value is in the default format -- to format the output you need to do a date formatter operation.